# vba error 13 with microsoft excel objects

Tags: excel, vba

So this error 13 started today. I have a button that sets the current year. This button is an ActiveX button(I like this over a Form button for organization reasons.) 
This is the code for the button.

```
Private Sub CurrentYear_Click()
        Call StartData
        Yr = Year(Now)
        Cells(1, 2).Value = Yr
        Call UpdateSheets
End Sub
```

StartData is the function I have for setup like `public Yr As Integer` and `Yr = Cells(1, 2).Value`. This is done because other data needs setup when if this or other buttons are pressed first. Now I'm getting the error on this line `Yr = Year(Now)` and I'll point I do not think this is a problem with my variable for these two(on a ActiveX scroll) work.

```
Private Sub YearChange_SpinDown()
    Call StartData
    Yr = Yr - 1
    Call UpdateSheets
End Sub
Private Sub YearChange_SpinUp()
    Call StartData
    Yr = Yr + 1
    Call UpdateSheets
End Sub
```

Now here is the twist, I put that top function in a module and ran off that and it works, I opened up a new workbook to test it and it works. So while I have workarounds for this I'll to know if I did something and if I can put it back.

Module with StartData

```
Public Yr As Integer
Public MonthNub As Integer
Public MonthNm As String
Public MonNam As String
Public LastMonthNub As Integer
Public LastMonthName As String
Public NextMonthNub As Integer
Public NextMonthName As String
Public WkN As Integer
Public WkDy As Integer
Public EndD As Integer
Public LEnD As Integer
Public MonthSheet As Worksheet
Public Week1 As Worksheet
Public Week2 As Worksheet
Public Week3 As Worksheet
Public Week4 As Worksheet
Public Week5 As Worksheet
Public Week6 As Worksheet
Public Sub StartData()
    Yr = Cells(1, 2).Value
    MonthNm = Cells(1, 1).Value
    MonthNub = Month(DateValue(MonthNm & " 01 " & Yr))
    MonNam = MonthName(MonthNub, True)

    Set MonthSheet = Worksheets(2)
    Set Week1 = Worksheets(3)
    Set Week2 = Worksheets(4)
    Set Week3 = Worksheets(5)
    Set Week4 = Worksheets(6)
    Set Week5 = Worksheets(7)
    Set Week6 = Worksheets(8)

    If MonthNub - 1 < 1 Then
        LastMonthNub = 12
    Else
        LastMonthNub = MonthNub - 1
    End If
    LastMonthName = MonthName(LastMonthNub, True)

    If MonthNub + 1 > 12 Then
        NextMonthNub = 1
    Else
        NextMonthNub = MonthNub + 1
    End If
    NextMonthName = MonthName(NextMonthNub, True)
End Sub
```

Comment: this could be a reference problem, in the immediate window of VBE run this and `debug.print Year(Now)` see if it returns the right answer

Comment: debug.print is also outputting error 13

Comment: What exact line gives the error ?

Comment: The Now() always needs the pair of parens.  Please update and try again.  Try  debug.print Year(Now())

Comment: `debug.print Year(Now)` and `debug.print Year(Now())` gave the error. `Option Explicit` on every module does not have an effect.